# tomcat web.xml cors.allowOrigin deleting entries

Tags: tomcat, liferay, web.xml

My Tomcat 6 "web.xml" looks like this:

```
  <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
           <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
           <param-value>GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
           <param-value>CONTENT-TYPE, ACCEPT, ORIGIN, x-requested-with, Cache-Control</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
            <param-value>http://host1.com:8080</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
            <param-value>http://host2.com:8585</param-value>
        </init-param>
          <init-param>
                    <param-name>cors.allowSubdomains</param-name>
                    <param-value>true</param-value>
            </init-param>
    </filter>
```

When I start up the Tomcat with Liferay, it deletes the "host2" entry (the 4 lines). No matter how many entries I have, it deletes everything except the first one.

What would cause this to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are running tomcat from Eclipse IDE. If not using eclipse then ignore the rest of the answer and if yes, please read on.

It is eclipse which is overriding the tomcat specific stuff, so there are two solutions to this:

1. Don't use eclipse to start/stop the server :D (easy, simple and obvious)
2. Rather than changing the `web.xml` in tomcat, change it in the `Servers` location, i.e. look into your eclipse workspace and you will find a folder `<your-eclipse-workspace>\Servers\<name-of-server-(tomcat 6)-at-localhos>-config\`. This is the location eclipse uses to override server specific files.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am not running Tomcat from the Eclipse IDE. I am starting Tomcat on the Linux server. We have since determined that Liferay is the limiting entity - it deletes all entries except one "cors.allowOrigin". So our solution is to put space-delimited multiple URLs within that one entry, such as: <param-value> http:url1 http:url2 http:url3 http:url4</param-value>. That has been working for us.

Comment: Oh! i didn't properly saw that this entry `<param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>` is repeated in the next set of `<init-param>`. By the way this is not liferay this is tomcat and even other servers would behave liket his, why? because `param-name` is used as a `key` to get the `value`, you can understand it like a `HashMap` which has unique keys. Will add another answer to include more details.

Comment: We have another capability running Tomcat and it permits two "cors.allowOrigin" values. I do understand if it's like a hash table and we are running fine with one entry with multiple values. Thank you for the information.